# Store and Skip input's - Strings

Tags: c, string, input

So I'm trying to Implement the following as input commands

```
score string number 
Record number as the score for the player whose name is string. No output is produced. Assume number is an integer between -999999999 and 999999999.

best string 
Output a line containing best string number where number is the best score recorded so far for the player whose name is string. 
Output ? instead of number if no score has been recorded for the player.

highscore 
Output a line containing highscore number where number is the highest score recorded for any player so far. Output highscore ? if no score has been recorded.

Any command other than score, best, highscore. Ignore the command and proceed to the next one.
```

Here is some sample-input/output

```
Sample Input

score FredFlintstonefromBedrock 10
score Wilma 20
score FredFlintstonefromBe 20
highscore
score Betty 30
highscore
best FredFlintstonefromBedrock
score FredFlintstonefromBedrock 25
best FredFlintstonefromBeyond
best Barney

Output for Sample Input

highscore 20
highscore 30
best FredFlintstonefromBe 20
best FredFlintstonefromBe 25
best Barney ?
```

I'm giving the following function readstring, http://ideone.com/jTq3l ... That produces true if it can read a string successfully. I'm thinking of storing the score's in an array... for more information http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/assignments/a10/. I also can't use heap storage.

My question is how do i store the names and thier score's. Also how would i differentiate between a number and a string ?

Here is what i have so far/ psuodocode:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "readstring.h"


    int main(void) {
    char *i = "";  
    int x = 0;     
    char s[1000];
    char* a[100];
    int b[100];

    while (readstring(s,20) != 0) {
     //if(s == "score")
     // void; (do nothing)

     // if s is a number;
     // a[x] = i;
     // b[x] = s;
     // x++;

     //if (s == "highscore");
     // printf("highscore %d\n", (maxof b);

     //if (i == "best") {
     // printf("best %s %d\n", s, (maxof a's correspoding score);

     // else  i = s;
}
}
```

I feel like the above^ is very wrong ... Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

> How do i store the names and their scores?

If you're using AVL trees, store both the name and the score in the nodes. Order the tree based on the score. However, name lookups would be O(n).

> How would i differentiate between a number and a string?

Using `strtol` from stdlib.h

> I feel like the [code] is very wrong ... Any suggestions?

Don't hard-code the length of the string. Instead write:

```
while (readstring(s, (sizeof s) - 1))
```

Since you're not maintaining state when you're reading single words from the input, your pseudo code won't detect malformed input like the following:

```
score Wilma
highscore 100
best
```

Comment: So im not allowed to use any heap storage, which means i cant use malloc, hence no AVL, :( ... I'm thinking that i will store the scores in an array, but i don't know about the names? any suggestions ?